# OnUserPreferenceChanged hang: DataGridView created in separate thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, datagridview, memory-leaks

Recently I made performance optimization by using controls creating and filling by data in separate thread (STA). After that I found a memory leak in the application: grids inherited from `DataGridView` were not released keeping large amounts of memory:
[image: dotMemory report]

After some investigation I found that the reason is subscription for `SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged` event:
[image: path]

So the goal is to get rid of this subscription to release the objects.
I spent time to test some approaches found by googling (for example this one: [Memory Leak in ToolStripTextBoxControl](http://memprofiler.com/articles/memleakintoolstriptextboxcontrol.aspx)), but did not succeed.

Comment: Why "-1"? What's wrong with the question?

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution. It's not perfect but solves the issue:
I have found that subscription/unsubscription for the event `SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged` is in methods `OnHandleCreated/OnHandleDestroyed` (class `DataGridView`).

```
public class MyDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    ...
    #region Memory leak fix

    int _eventSubscriptionCount;

    /// <summary>
    /// Hack to fix event handler leak
    /// </summary>
    private void MemoryLeakFix()
    {
        Disposed += OnDisposed;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// In some cases subscription keeps PinkDataGridView (and containing it controls) from removing by GC
    /// </summary>
    private void OnDisposed(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _eventSubscriptionCount; i++)
        {
            base.OnHandleDestroyed(new EventArgs()); // unsubscribe SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged
        }
    }

    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _eventSubscriptionCount);
    }

    protected override void OnHandleDestroyed(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleDestroyed(e);
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref _eventSubscriptionCount);
    }

    #endregion Memory leak fix
}
```